# How do I do this query in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For each `site_id` I have to determine if the `plan_id` was `1` in the past (past means a lesser `id`) *and* was not `1` at some point before that, for example:

```
create table billing (id int, site_id int, plan_id int);

insert into billing values
(40301, 1, 1), (40302, 1, 16), (40304, 1, 15),
(40401, 2, 1), (40402, 2, 16), (40403, 2, 1), (40404, 2, 15);
```

Should return:

```
site_id = 1, did_return = false
site_id = 2, did_return = true
```

The number of `billing` records for a given `site_id` could be 1 or dozens.

I have tried nested queries:

```
select (
   select (
      select id from billing where plan_id <> 1 and id < b2.id order by id desc limit 1
   )
   from billing b2 where plan_id = 1 and id < b1.id order by id desc limit 1
)
from billing b1
order by id desc limit 1
```

But Redshift does not support this type of query:

```
ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error
```

Is there another way to do this? Redshift is similar to Postgres, so there's likely a postgres answer for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with joins:

```
select b1.site_id, min(b3.id)
from billing b1
left join billing b2 on (b2.id < b1.id and b1.site_id = b2.site_id and b2.plan_id = 1)
left join billing b3 on (b3.id < b2.id and b2.site_id = b3.site_id and b3.plan_id <> 1)
group by b1.site_id
```